# How do I avoid duplicated sitemap content?

Tags: seo, sitemap, google-search

I have a php dynamic wallpaper site http://www.fondolandia.com , it's been online for a year, recently I've submited the page to a sitemap builder site, and  within the sitemap file i found out that some links point to the same image in different resolutions, example

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.fondolandia.com/portal/display/51_palacio-europa1356656199/1600x1200</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.64</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://www.fondolandia.com/portal/display/51_palacio-europa1356656199/1280x960</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.64</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://www.fondolandia.com/portal/display/51_palacio-europa1356656199/1024x768</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.64</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://www.fondolandia.com/portal/display/51_palacio-europa1356656199/800x600</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.64</priority>
</url>
```

Actually 4 links to the same image but in different resolutions, should i delete those links from the sitemap, being that another link points to an overview of the same image.

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.fondolandia.com/portal/fondo/51_palacio-europa1356656199</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
```

While doing  a site:url i see many links to old images that have been deleted from the site and appear listed on the search results, should google solve this once it crawls my site or should i do something ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, the duplicate links in the sitemap are OK, but each page should have a [canonical link](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) to tell google that they are really the same thing.

As for the deleted pages in search results, google should solve this as well when it re-crawls the pages as long as your site is returning an appropriate status code (e.g. a 404 or a 301 redirect to some other page)